# Iterate elements of an n-demensional array

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

I need to iterate over an n-dimensional array of numbers where n is only known at runtime. For example, an array of dimensions (2,4,6,5). This has 240 elements and I'd like to be able to iterate over the i, j, k, and l indices. I could flatten the data and access it linearly, but then I'd need to know how a specific point in the linear array related to a coordinate, i, j, k l, which I'm not sure how to do.

Often for fixed n such as 2D or 3D, we'd use nested for loops. But with n unknown, it's not possible to do that. Can anyone point me to information on this? I've tried searching multiple times but I get topics like iterating over a list, where the sublists are objects and can iterate those recursively. But in this case, the array is a simple array of numbers. I'm currently stuck.

Comment: You technically don't need the dimensions. You only need the depth. The dimensions can be figured out by simply checking if `i+1` is defined at any branch, i.e. replace the for loops with a while loop. The depth is required to know how many of these while loops to "nest". You can find the depth by taking a single pass through 0th-index, assuming a homogenous & uniform array, until you hit a non-array element. You can also do the depth discovery on the go but it requires a bit more precision in placement and I don't have the energy atm to figure it out. This how type providers work more or less

Comment: This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788832/calculating-the-address-of-an-element-in-an-n-dimensional-array - There are 2 algorithms required: (1) convert multi-dim subscripts to a single linear address for example X(1,2,3,5) --> S(9) , (2) An algorithm to take the position in single dim and get the subscripts in the above example, given 9 --> 1,2,3,5. Which one do you want?

Comment: The second one would help (I can do the first), i.e given an index 9 in a flattened array what would be the coordinate? I have access to the flattened array as well as all the dimensions.

Comment: You may want to reference [this code](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/Happy_Hacking_CXX/blob/master/hhxx/multi_view.hpp).

Answer (score 1):

For an n-dimensional array with dimensions d = [d0, d1, d2, ..., d(n-1)] you can get the ith element the following way:

1. Build the product of the dimensions from right to left (p[0] is not needed but it tells you how many values are in the array):

   ```
   p[n - 1] = d[n - 1]
   for (j = n - 2; j >= 0; j--)
       p[j] = p[j + 1] * d[j]
   ```
2. Now you can get get the indexes the following way:

   ```
   for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
       index[j] = i / p[j + 1] // integer division or use floor i.e. round down
       i = i % p[j + 1]
   }
   index[n - 1] = i
   ```

And to answer the other question, how to iterate? Depends on the programming language. Recursion is a possibility. Pseudo-code:

```
function iterate(arr) {
    if (isArray(arr)) {
        for (a in arr) {
            iterate(a)
        }
    } else {
        // do something with value arr
    }
}
```

The above also works if every element in an array can be an array of any dimension or a value. The index calculation on the other hand doesn't work in that case.

Alternative, if ther is no isArray():

```
function iterate(arr, dimensions, depth) {
    if (depth < dimensions.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < dimensions[depth]; i++) {
            iterate(arr[i], dimensions, depth + 1)
        }
    } else {
        // do something with value arr
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen the recursive method you show, but I've not been quite sure how to use it because I don't have the equivalent of the isArray() test.  What I have is a multidimensional array of numbers which are indexed by i,j,k, etc

Comment: @rhody added alternatve. It depends on the programming language I think what is the best way to do this. If the parameter arr cannot be a value too you should only make recursive calls to depth < dimensions.length - 1 and otherwise iterate over arr to get the values for the last dimension.

Comment: Thanks, I give the alternative a try, will report back later